# Is it possible to pause and resume rake tasks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

Is there any option for pause and resume the `rake tasks` in `rails`. I've one `rake task` that will run every night but some times it needs to be paused and run another one. How can I achieve this?

Thanking you advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the rake task through a cron, I would recommend to use `whenever gem` for that, in your `rake task` you can put a check that match your some case condition and if that satisfy run different rake task you were saying, by check I mean put a conditional `block(if)` that checks if the some time condition you are saying fulfills, then fire another rake task from there and return.

You can share your code and exact scenario, it will be more clear that way.

Comment: one more doubt. I've one table called "keywords" if user added new keyword current task will need to be paused . how can I achieve this what will be the condition for checking this.

Comment: i think your relations should be like this, a user may has many keywords, then you should put a top unless block at you rake task which says unless(user.keywords.blank?) then run you code, wrap your code inside this block.